# Java3d - Jar file contains error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, noclassdeffounderror, java-3d

I am currently having a problem running a jar file created by eclipse.

Within eclipse I can run my project using the run function and the project runs exactly as expected.

The same applies to compiling and running the code from command line using `javac Menu.java` to compile and `java Menu` to run.

Both of these run correctly and do not return the error I receive when running the jar file.

The jar file was created in eclipse by exporting the project. But when i run the jar file the application refuses to response when opening any JFrames containing Java3d. Upon debugging the jar file i receive the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D
```

This normally would lead me to believe that my CLASSPATH is incorrect but since the project runs from command line this doesn't seem likely.

Any help or pointers would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: That means that your JAR file is not fond in JAVA_PATH for Java Runtime Env.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution which works.

Instead of simply creating a jar file, you can created a runnable Jar file.

When asked under library handling in the export process, selecting 'package required libraries into generated JAR' solves this issue and allows it to run on all computers, even ones without Java3D installed.